# LINQ Nested query with appropriate quantifiers and restrictions

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables A & B as below:

**Table A**

**W X Y**
1   7   5
2   0   7
3   1   7
4   4   4
5   4   7

**Table B**

**Q Z   C   D**
1   1   7   5
2   1   0   7
3   1   1   7
4   1   4   4

I want to get those values of W for whom X & Y combination exactly matches those combination of C & D in Table B for whom Z = 1.

I have tried following query:

```
var query = A.Where(u =>
                       B.Where(a => a.Z == 1)
                        .Select(a => a.C)
                        .Contains(u.X))
              .Where(u =>
                       B.Where(a => a.Z == 1)
                       .Select(a => a.D)
                       .Contains(u.Y))
               .Select(a => new { WIds = a.W });
```

so in above cases, query result should give: W = {1,2,3,4} however I am getting extra value of 5 as well.  W = {1,2,3,4,5}. I think it is not considering the combination as a whole. Can anyone help me what am I doing wrong in this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it using `Any`:-

```
var result = A.Where(x =>
                        B.Any(p => p.Z == 1 && p.C == x.X && p.D == x.Y)
                     )
              .Select(x => x.W);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/URrYzy)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
 var query = A.Where(a =>
                       B.Any(b => b.Z == 1 && a.X == b.C && a.Y == b.D))
               .Select(a => new { WIds = a.W });
```

Comment: That doesn't compile, you cannot return an `IEnumerable<A>` to a `Where`

Comment: Oki, I'm not use to the syntax, thank you. I'll edit

Comment: though giving some error, however I got the idea from your answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are just checking whether the current `X` matches any `C` and the current `Y` matches any `D`, instead of matching them as a group. You could do this with a simpler query:

```
var query = A
    .Where(a => B.Any(b => b.Z == 1 && b.C == a.X && b.D == a.Y))
    .Select(a => new { WIds = a.W });
```

Comment: Thnks Camilo. Great to be learning on StackOverFlow from u people.